# uboot: Overwrite mmcboot environment variable not working

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, u-boot

I am trying to overwrite the uboot `bootcmd` environment variable but it keeps on using the default setting. I know I can set this in the uboot prompt and it will save permanently but I want to be able to set it automatically through the code.

In my board config file I have

```
#include <config_distro_bootcmd.h>

#ifdef CONFIG_BOOTCOMMAND
#undef CONFIG_BOOTCOMMAND
#endif
#define CONFIG_BOOTCOMMAND \
        "echo hello world; " \
```

But when I uboot begins and I `printenv mmcboot` the default value set is configured:

```
    => printenv mmcboot
    mmcboot=mmc dev ${mmcdev}; setenv devnum ${mmcdev}; setenv devtype mmc; 
    if mmc rescan; then echo SD/MMC found on device ${mmcdev};if run loadimage; 
    then if test ${boot_fit} -eq 1; then run loadfit; else run mmcloados;fi;fi;fi;
    =>
```

If in the defconfig file I set `CONFIG_DISTRO_DEFAULTS=n` I get a compilation error.

```
include/config_distro_bootcmd.h:314:2: error: expected '}' before 'BOOT_TARGET_DEVICES_references_PXE_without_CONFIG_CMD_DHCP_or_PXE'
  BOOT_TARGET_DEVICES_references_PXE_without_CONFIG_CMD_DHCP_or_PXE
  ^
include/config_distro_bootcmd.h:314:2: note: in definition of macro 'BOOTENV_DEV_NAME_PXE'
  BOOT_TARGET_DEVICES_references_PXE_without_CONFIG_CMD_DHCP_or_PXE
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
include/configs/am335x_p230.h:101:2: note: in expansion of macro 'BOOTENV_DEV_NAME'
  func(PXE, pxe, na) \
  ^~~~
include/config_distro_bootcmd.h:320:18: note: in expansion of macro 'BOOT_TARGET_DEVICES'
  "boot_targets=" BOOT_TARGET_DEVICES(BOOTENV_DEV_NAME) "\0"
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
include/config_distro_bootcmd.h:337:2: note: in expansion of macro 'BOOTENV_BOOT_TARGETS'
  BOOTENV_BOOT_TARGETS \
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
include/configs/am335x_p230.h:208:2: note: in expansion of macro 'BOOTENV'
  BOOTENV
  ^~~~~~~
include/env_default.h:108:2: note: in expansion of macro 'CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS'
  CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS
```

Comment: If you're trying to change env var **bootcmd**, then why do you use the command  `printenv mmcboot`??? That displays the value of env var **mmcboot**.  If you want to see the value of env var **bootcmd**, then use the command `printenv bootcmd`.  Or are you trying to change **mmcboot**, as the title suggests?  Your post is confusing.  **bootcmd** and **mmcboot** are two distinct environment variables, but you seem to think they are synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to mess around with coding. Use

```
make menuconfig
```

Search for *CONFIG_BOOTCOMMAND* and edit the value.